# Problems making resource URLs portable on CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, resource-urls

I'm getting a warning for my Wordpress install of CiviCRM, under the title **Resource URLs: Make them portable**:

> Resource URLs may use absolute paths, relative paths, or variables.
>   Absolute paths are more difficult to maintain. To maximize
>   portability, consider using a variable in each URL (eg "[cms.root]" or
>   "[civicrm.files]").

On the Resource URLs page it brings me to, I have the *CiviCRM Resource URL* as

```
http:// <path to Wordpress install> /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm
```

The others on this page which are populated are *Image Uplaod URL*

```
[civicrm.files]persist/contribute
```

and *Extension Resource URL*

```
[civicrm.files]/ext/
```

But when I try to change *CiviCRM Resource URL* to

```
[civicrm.root]/
```

which is the recommended portable value from the help button near the top, and then save it, the value is not saved, and reverts to the absolute URL above, and the warning persists.

I have installed CiviCRM 4.7.27 on Wordpress 4.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason that the value may not change is because it's overridden in `civicrm.settings.php`.  See the [Overriding Settings](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/) section of the documentation.

An upcoming version of CiviCRM will make overridden settings clearly non-editable, but for now, check `civicrm.settings.php`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I might just hide the warning for now so if it'll be fixed soon.

Comment: The upcoming version won't fix the warning; it'll just make it clear whether the problem I identified is the one you're having.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in 4.7.26 in order to handle the multiple ways that WordPress can be installed on various hosts, we are determining the correct path and setting both the path to the site (front end) and the path to the backend (wp-admin) in civicrm.settings.php.

The resource url status warning will need to be updated to handle this.

Comment: I'm still getting the warning to make Resource URLs portable, and in Administer/System Settings/Reource URLs, the CiviCRM Resource URL value is not in a field that can be edited.

Comment: Had to edit the line in civicrm.settings.php to "$civicrm_setting['domain']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = '[civicrm.root]/';" and the portable Resource URLs warning is finally gone. Guessing the absolute path is an artifact of the installer.